# Convert a PGP Public Key

Tags: java, bouncycastle, x509, public, pgp

Does anybody know if there is a way to convert a public key with the pgp public key format to the X.509 key format? Maybe using Bouncy Castle or something familiar?

Because right now I am able to decode a X.509 public key using X509EncodedKeySpecs and PublicKey, but this doesn't work with the PGP key format.

```
byte[] decodeValue = Base64.decode(schluesselstring.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodeValue);
try {
    KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    try {
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFact.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
        schluessel = "schluessel";
        Log.d("TEST", "publicKey = " + publicKey.toString());
        Log.d("TEST", "Algorithm = " + publicKey.getAlgorithm());
        Log.d("TEST", "Format = " + publicKey.getFormat());
      }
  catch...
  }
```

When I try to use this code on a PGP key I get an error message because it's not ANSC.1 . I also tried to use different KeySpecs but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

The standard that "X.509" (SPKI) and "PKCS8" keys, and other things like certificates, use is [Abstract Syntax Notation One ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One). Standard Java crypto doesn't handle PGP but yes BouncyCastle (bcpg) can do this just fine (updated 2021-02: JcaPGPKeyConverter does the whole job, and for all algorithms):

```
static void SO40831894PGPPubkeyCvtBC (String[] args) throws Exception {
    // adapted from org.bouncycastle.openpgp.examples.PubringDump
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream (args[0])){
        PGPPublicKeyRingCollection    pubRings = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(
                PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in), new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());
        Iterator<PGPPublicKeyRing>    rIt = pubRings.getKeyRings();
        while (rIt.hasNext()){
            PGPPublicKeyRing    pgpPub = (PGPPublicKeyRing)rIt.next();
            Iterator<PGPPublicKey>    it = pgpPub.getPublicKeys();
            while (it.hasNext()){
                PGPPublicKey    pgpKey = (PGPPublicKey)it.next();
                System.out.println(pgpKey.getClass().getName()
                        + " KeyID: " + Long.toHexString(pgpKey.getKeyID())
                        + " type: " + pgpKey.getAlgorithm()
                        + " fingerprint: " + new String(Hex.encode(pgpKey.getFingerprint())));
                /* don't need to do this >>>
                BCPGKey bcKey = pgpKey.getPublicKeyPacket().getKey();
                //System.out.println (bcKey.getClass().getName());
                if( bcKey instanceof RSAPublicBCPGKey ){
                    RSAPublicBCPGKey bcRSA = (RSAPublicBCPGKey)bcKey;
                    RSAPublicKeySpec specRSA = new RSAPublicKeySpec( bcRSA.getModulus(), bcRSA.getPublicExponent());
                    PublicKey jceKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(specRSA);
                <<< instead just: */
                {
                    PublicKey jceKey = new JcaPGPKeyConverter().getPublicKey(pgpKey);
                    // if you want to use the key in JCE, jceKey is now ready
                    // if you want to write "X.509" (SPKI) DER format to a file: 
                    Files.write(new File(args[1]).toPath(), jceKey.getEncoded());
                    // if you want to write in PEM, bouncycastle can do that too
                    return;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```